# Jenkins Integration with CVS

Tags: jenkins

**How Jenkins can be integrated with CVS. If somebody can provide step by step instructions then it would be of great help.**

I tried installing Jenkins but everytinme, i am getting below error.

Started by user anonymous
Building in workspace C:\Program Files\Jenkins\jobs\Umesh CVS Testing\workspace
Using locally configured password for connection to :ext:ssh@dwagda01:/usr/local/cvsroot
cvs checkout -P -D 12 Nov 2014 10:33:54 -0600 -d workspace dwagda01 
ERROR: CVS Authentication failed: null
org.netbeans.lib.cvsclient.connection.AuthenticationException: SSH connection failed.
    at org.netbeans.lib.cvsclient.connection.SSHConnection.open(SSHConnection.java:141)
    at org.netbeans.lib.cvsclient.Client$1.run(Client.java:374)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Documents and Settings\LocalService.ssh\id_rsa (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.KeyPair.load(KeyPair.java:524)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.IdentityFile.newInstance(IdentityFile.java:40)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.JSch.addIdentity(JSch.java:389)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.JSch.addIdentity(JSch.java:370)
    at org.netbeans.lib.cvsclient.connection.SSHConnection.open(SSHConnection.java:135)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Documents and Settings\LocalService.ssh\id_rsa (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.(Unknown Source)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Util.fromFile(Util.java:492)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.KeyPair.load(KeyPair.java:521)
    ... 6 more
ERROR: Cvs task failed
Finished: FAILURE

Answer (score 3):

I got stuck with the same error.

As my setup did not require a private key, I didn't want to configure it in Jenkins.

However, you MUST have a private key, even if you don't use it. I created one from scratch and then things worked fine. I did not put the public key on the CVS server or anything like that - it seems that Jenkins just needs a key file and then it works...

To create a private key, I used putty - the PUTTYGEN.EXE file. Download the putty zip file (google it) and extracted out PUTTYGEN.EXE, then run it, create a new key pair, same the private key with no passphrase, load the private key, export it using the menu option Conversions -> Export OpenSSH key to "id_rsa". Then, I put that file in a folder I called "ssh" under my Jenkins folder, changed the Jenkins config to point to it and I was away...

Comment: Would it be possible to add a second SSH key in order for a separate project to connect to eg GitHub ?

Answer (score 1):

I got a similar error using extssh and have it resolved now, thought of posting it in case anyone lands here.

1. Jenkins > Manage Jenkins > Configure System > CVS section

Set 'CVS Root' to

> :ext:@host.name:path/to/repo

It should not contain the username or password as they will be set in their own fields in Jenkins; it is enough to provide 'ext' here even if the connection type is 'extssh' in Eclipse

2. Jenkins > Manage Jenkins > Configure System > CVS section

Make a note of the 'Private Key Location'

In my case it was like /opt/app/username/.ssh/id_rsa

3. To [generate key](https://www.sophos.com/en-us/support/knowledgebase/115708.aspx), go to the location in Unix and generate the key

> bash-4.1$ cd /opt/app/username/.ssh
>
> bash-4.1$ ssh-keygen
>
> Generating public/private rsa key pair. Enter file in which to save the key  (/opt/fedex/efs/.ssh/id_rsa): **id_rsa**

4. Under job configuration, provide the same CVSROOT

   > :ext:@host.name:path/to/repo

Build should now be able to pick source from CVS.